# How to show only unique invoice numbers on sql

Tags: sql

I'm trying to only show rows in my table where the invoice number is unique. There are sometimes multiple invoices against an order but want to display invoices numbers that only appear once. I'm struggling with the DISTINCT function as that returns all rows.
This is what i have so far:

```
SELECT
i.invoice_number [Invoice Number],
po.order_number [Order Number],
i.invoice_date [Invoice Date],
i_s.expenditure  [Expenditure],

FROM invoice i

LEFT JOIN project_order po ON i.project_orderid = po.project_orderid
LEFT JOIN invoice_split i_s ON i.invoiceid = i_s.invoiceid
```

Comment: If you have multiple rows, which do you want?

Comment: You would need to use either GROUP BY with HAVING or some window functions for that. Please provide more details (which sql, maybe some example structure, etc. and then we'll be able to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you want invoice numbers that appear only once in the result set of your query, you can use aggregation or window functions:

```
SELECT i.invoice_number as [Invoice Number],
       MAX(po.order_number) as [Order Number],
       MAX(i.invoice_date) as [Invoice Date],
       MAX(i_s.expenditure) as [Expenditure]
FROM invoice i LEFT JOIN
     project_order po
     ON i.project_orderid = po.project_orderid LEFT JOIN 
     invoice_split i_s
     ON i.invoiceid = i_s.invoiceid
GROUP BY i.invoice_number
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```